# How to get oldest file in ftp directory using bash script

Tags: bash, sorting, curl, ftp, directory

I have a working script that get all file list in a ftp directory and sae it in a local file with this:

```
curl -s -l ftp://username:password@ftpserver.com/directory/ > source.txt
```

Now, I need to sort this result by creation date instead of name. I only need to write the oldest file name in the source.txt file. Is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: If I use curl with its option `-l` I get only a list of filenames.

Comment: Are you looking really for creation date or for last modification date?

Comment: I only need to write the file name in the source.txt file. It Works using curl -l. But now, I need to sort the results by date, to get the oldest file first. It is not important the date, I only need the filename.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7568126/3776858

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally this script Works for me: lftp -u user,password -e "cls --sort=date; quit" ftpserveraddress/Folder 2> /dev/null | tail -n 1

Answer (score 2):

To get filename (and further informations) about file with oldest modification date in a given directory with `lftp`:

Example:

```
lftp -u anonymous,anonymous -e "ls -t; quit" ccrma-ftp.stanford.edu/pub | tail -n 1
```

Comment: You may want to add `| grep "^-"` in there before the `tail` in order to only list files rather than directories.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Thank you for this hint.

Comment: It works, this command returns the oldest file in the ftp directory. It shows date, size and filename. How can I do to show only the filename?

Comment: Finally this script Works for me: lftp -u user,password -e "cls --sort=date; quit" ftpserveraddress/Folder 2> /dev/null | tail -n 1