# FTP download latest file using FileMaker or Applescript

Tags: ftp, applescript, filemaker

I currently use Insert URL in order to download certain files from an external FTP location, which I have managed to get working perfectly using the following curl options

> --user " & $usr & ":" & $pw & " -o Stock-Summary.csv"

This works as hoped and downloads the file from the FTP, however, the company who provides us with these files has "moved the goalposts" so to speak.

For whatever reason they are now prefixing and suffixing random numbers to said file, so I need to tweak this to somehow only get the latest version of this file which now looks something like this -

> 7818023-Stock_Summary-035831

Any advice or different approaches would be greatly appreciated as I am simply a novice trying to help out a family friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the previous answer, [Retrieving the last modified file in a directory over FTP using a bash script with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568126/retrieving-the-last-modified-file-in-a-directory-over-ftp-using-a-bash-script-wi?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

In particular, this line of Bash,

```
curl --user <<USERNAME>>:<<PASSWORD>> ftp://<<SERVERURL>> 2>/dev/null | grep "Stock_Summary" | awk -F\  '{print $9}' | sort -n -t- -k3,4 -k1,2 -k2,2 | tail -1
```

will return the name of the last modified file in the directory that matches the given grep pattern. Then you can take the result of that call and feed the file name (with the extra identifiers) into your existing AppleScript.

```
set theFileName to do shell script "<<SHELL LINE ABOVE>>"
```

You may have to play around with the file pattern for grep to get something that will work for you.

Then you'd go back to your existing code and make it something like,

```
--user " & $usr & ":" & $pw & " -o " & theFileName
```

NB: remove and fill in everything between and including the << and >>.

In AppleScript this might look like:

```
on GetFileNameToPull(server, username, password, filePattern)
    set theScriptToRun to "curl --user " & username & ":" & password & " ftp://" & server & " 2>/dev/null | grep '" & filePattern & "' | awk -F\\  '{print $9}' | sort -n -t- -k3,4 -k1,2 -k2,2 | tail -1"
    set theFileName to do shell script theScriptToRun
    return theFileName
end GetFileNameToPull

on GetFileNameFromFTPServer(server, username, password, remoteFileName, localFileName)
    set theScriptToRun to "curl --silent --show-error --user " & username & ":" & password & " ftp://" & server & "/" & remoteFileName & " -o " & localFileName
    do shell script theScriptToRun
end GetFileNameFromFTPServer

on run
    set username to "USERNAME"
    set thePassword to "PASSWORD"
    set server to "SERVERNAME"

    set pathToDownload to "/path/to/download/to"

    set theRemoteFileName to GetFileNameToPull(server, username, thePassword, "Stock_Summary")
    set theLocalFileName to pathToDownload & "/" & theRemoteFileName

    GetFileNameFromFTPServer(server, username, thePassword, theRemoteFileName, theLocalFileName)
end run
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to extract "Stock_Summary" from the new file identifier, then this will do that:

```
on StripNumbers(FileLong)
    set x to offset of "-" in FileLong
    set temp to characters (x + 1) thru -1 of FileLong as string
    set x to offset of "-" in temp
    set temp to characters 1 thru (x - 1) of temp as string
    return temp
end StripNumbers

on run
        set FileLong to "7818023-Stock_Summary-035831"
        set FileShort to my StripNumbers(FileLong)
end run
```

Then you can add the extension and run your FTP script.

Comment: I'm sorry if I sound stupid,  I literally know nothing what so ever about Applescripts, I can barely even operate a Mac let alone write full scripts haha! Where would the FTP string be incorporated here?